# Logical error in Java programming

Tags: java, android, math

```
case R.id.bTanx:
        temp=(float) (number/0.0174532925);
        num=Math.tan(temp);
        display.setText("Your Result is   " + num);
```

Guys I'm not able to get "Your Result is  1" when `number = 45` ,by this code.Please help.
As `tan(45)=1` in degrees.i have converted it.but no desired result.

Comment: Where does Javascript or Eclipse come into this? You should look into the way you're converting degrees to radians, too... (hint: examine temp, and see whether it's what you expect)

Comment: Use multiply instead of division.

Comment: Why is people downvoting this? Can't newbies join the community?

Comment: use number*0.0174532925 and not number/0.0174532925

Comment: @RamonBoza I agree, I think the OP establishes a valid question, provides the information needed to solve it and demonstrates their attempt.  It would have been nice to see a more complete example, however it does appear they are new.

Comment: What is the result you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert degrees to radian you first need to convert the degrees to a factor (of the circles circumference) by dividing by 360 degrees. Next you multiply by 2PI rad (which is the circumference of a 'unit circle').

When looking at the units you do this: degrees / degrees * radians = radians

So where you divide by 0.017 (2*PI / 360), you need to multiply instead:

```
temp = (float) (number * 0.0174532925);
```

Furthermore it is nicer (more clear) if you do not use 'magic numbers' and add comments (so people know what you are doing):

```
// Convert to rad
temp = (float) (number * 2 * Math.PI / 360);
```

And/or even use the available Java functionality:

```
// Convert to rad
temp = Math.toRadians(number);
```

Comment: thankyou but this wont convert the number to radians. we convert degree to radians by radian= (degree )/ .0174

Comment: I added an explanation why you need to multiply instead of divide to my answer. Hopefully it will make it more clear what is going wrong.